# I²C with energia and EK-TM4C1294XL

Tags: microcontroller

I want to communicate with a SHT21 Sensor from a EK-TM4C1294XL Board.
But it seems that I2C communication is quite difficult with energia.

I used different setups with external Pullup, used the internal pullup and also no pullup. then i tried both I2C interfaces by setting `Wire.setModule(0)` or `Wire.setModule(1)` but in all cases the result is that either everything freezes in the `Wire.endTransmission()` function or i receive only bytes filled with 0.

I basically used this library: https://github.com/elechouse/SHT21_Arduino and modified the example script like this:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SHT2x.h>


void setup()
{
  Wire.setModule(1); // SCL = PN_5 (pin 49), SDA = PN_4 (Pin 50)
  Wire.begin();
  // optional use this:
  //   pinMode(PN_5, INPUT_PULLUP);
  //   pinMode(PN_4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Humidity(%RH): ");
  Serial.print(SHT2x.GetHumidity());
  Serial.print(" Temperature(C): ");
  Serial.println(SHT2x.GetTemperature());

  delay(1000);
}
```

There is a boosterpack containing the SHT21 as well, but i did not found any sample code for that... I did not managed yet to get the C stuff running on my linux machine, probably I2C is broken in the energia lib?

Edit: it seems that there is a bug in the library too. The timing must be precise and also 3 bytes are requested and only 2 read. when reading the last byte i do not get good values but at least the loop does not freeze.

Comment: Firstly. I2C requires pull-ups on SDA and SCL, so you must use these in some shape or form. Your code doesn't look incorrect, so if it were me I would first check the signals using a scope if you are able to - you will be able to see whether the command byte is being written at all. If not, it would point to a bug in the Wire library, which the Internet suggests has existed for a while in the standard Arduino core.

Comment: yes i know that, but several arduino style products use the internal pullups of the controller. It seams that the launchpad does not have this feature (or at least it is not enabled). I used external pullups now but i receive only gibberish... I will debug it tomorrow with an oscilloscope, maybe my breadboard has too high capacitance for the speed of the I²C bus.